# Split string with comma delimiter but not if it is a currency value using C#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have to split a string which contains normal values as well as currency values

```
i.e. aaa,bbb,$33,222,ccc,$22,000
```

Output expected :

```
-aaa
-bbb
-$33,222
-ccc
-$22,000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just giving a non-regex answer for some variety. You could do the following:

```
String[] MySplit(String str)
{
    bool currency = false;
    char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < str.Length(); ++i)
    {
       if(chars[i] == '$')
          currency=true;
       else
       if(currency && chars[i] == ',')
       {
           chars[i] = '.';
           currency = false;
       }
    }
    return new String(chars).Split(",");
}
```

This replaces the currency commas with full stops or whatever you want so that you can comfortably split the string on commas. You can always change it back to commas once you have the tokens. Note that this only works under the assumptions that currency values will always have decimals.

Comment: @pikachu Fantastic. Please remember to accept it if you end up using it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just split according to the below regex.

```
@",(?!\d)"
```

This will match all the commas which are not followed by a digit. `(?!\d)` asserts that the match must not be followed by a digit.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jA2sQ2/1)

In c# this should work.

```
@"(?<!\$\d+),(?!\d+)"
```

Comment: Can you please explain this regex.

Comment: @pikachu this will break in case of `aaa,123` do you want that?

Comment: i dont want that, my string is like this : aaa,$12,000,12345,bbb,56789,ccc and i want the final array to be like : -aaa - $12000 -12345 -bbb -56789 -ccc

Comment: @pikachu i think my update will give you the output you expected for the above input.

Comment: @AvinashRaj guess you should remove the old answer as the OP's expectation is not being fulfilled by it

Comment: @vks why? old answer satisfies the question he posted at first. But for the comment, i added the second one..

Comment: @AvinashRaj no it doesnt `but not if it is a currency value `

Comment: The result that i am getting from the above expression is like : -aaa - $12,000 12345 - bbb 56789 - ccc; The expression is actually clubbing all the digit values which are occurring simultaneously which is not expected

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest grab the capture instead of split.

```
(\$\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)*)|([^,\n]+)
```

Try this.See demo.You can later append `-` to each `capture` or `group` result.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/14